# How do you make SQLAlchemy return a hybrid_property with __dict__?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Pydantic classes and frequently move from ORM objects to Pydantic Class Objects.

I am getting a key error when @hybrid_property is involved in the operation.

```
print(chart.__dict__['is_saved_chart'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'is_saved_chart'
```

In several instances, I am using a @hybrid_property to all the data returned on an ORM object.  When I try to move these to a Pydantic Class where the hybrid property is required, I get type errors - because it doesn't exist in the _*dict*_ object.

```
class Chart(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), index=True)
    instrument_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("instrument.id"), index=True)

    # Relationships
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="charts")
    instrument = relationship("Instrument", back_populates="charts")

    @hybrid_property
    def is_saved_chart(self):
        return True if self.chart_object is not None else False
```

When I print this way, I get the expected result:

```
print(chart.is_saved_chart)
True
```

When I try for the _*dict*_:

```
print(chart.__dict__['is_saved_chart'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'is_saved_chart'
```

I think I understand @hybrid_property is bound at the class and instance level.  The data is present in the ORM object, it just doesn't drop out with the _*dict*_.

I get the same behavior from FastAPI's jsonable_encoder().

**So, how do you make SQLAlchemy return a hybrid_property with **dict**?**

Comment: You don't, hybrid props are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and as such exist in the class, not an instance. When you do `chart.is_saved_chart` Python tries to lookup the attribute from the instance, and then has a look in the class and finds the descriptor there.

Comment: Any direction on how to achieve a virtual column that functions with __dict__? I thought __dict__ worked up the chain from the instance to the object based on [invoking descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)

Comment: Use `getattr()` instead.

Comment: Are you using [orm mode](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances)?

Comment: SuperShoot - please post that as the answer.  I figured it out just prior to your post.  I was using from_obj on a dict.  I should have been using from_orm on a SqlAlchemy session.query object.